# Can script tag appear before title and meta tags?

Tags: html, google-analytics, title, meta

I am studying how to embed Google Analytics tracking code into my web page. Based on the document at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ , it said "The code should be added near the top of the  tag and before any other script or CSS tags", in such a case, can the code be put before title and meta tags , like this:

```
    <HEAD>

    <!-- 2019-03-01: Google Analytics Tracking Code(async) for xxxx, based on Google online help -->
    <script>
        window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
      ga('create', 'UA-xxxx', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
      ga('require', 'linker');
      ga('linker:autoLink', ['shareit.com', 'mycommerce.com'] );    
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>

    <TITLE>xxxxxx</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <META name="DESCRIPTION" content="xxxxxx">
```

This looks a bit strange. So I just wonder if it is OK to put script tag before title & meta tags?

Thanks

Comment: `CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"` — Support for UTF-8 has been excellent for decades. There should be no reason to use Latin 1 in 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no ill effects, but no improvements either. GA code should go before CSS and script tags because downloading them might block the browser and delay downloading the Google Script and (more importantly) delay running the ga command queue. Meta tags do not really have influence on the processing, so it doesn't matter if they come before the code, but browsers are not really picky as the where in the header title and meta show up.

Answer (score 4):

The only restriction you face is that `<meta charset` must be [must be serialized completely within the first 1024 bytes of the document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#specifying-the-documents-character-encoding).

Putting script elements before it could violate that constraint.

Comment: I had put the Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager scripts before the <meta charset and lost points on a Lighthouse review for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge you can use the script tags before head tags, if you want to prioritize your execution of the script then use it just below the starting of head tags.